# View with the same size of another

Tags: android

I need to create a View Placeholder: a View that doesn't draw nothing, but has the same dimension of a given View. I'm trying to achieve that by doing so:

```
public class ViewPlaceHolder extends View {

    View target;

    public ViewPlaceHolder(View target) {
        super(target.getContext());
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        target.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(target.getMeasuredWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(target.getMeasuredHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }

}
```

By now it doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot

PS: I need a placeholder to make same animations and effects on a scrollView

PPS: additional explanation:
 the result of target.getMeasuredWidth() and target.getMeasuredHeight() is correct, but the ViewPlaceholder has a complete random height (the width seem to be ok)

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I've added some details

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I made an error on the layout hierarchy, now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If the target view is drawn , then you can read its dimensions by calling the getWidth() and getHeight() methods. So, if these methods does not return 0 , you can apply the setLayoutParams on the ViewPlaceHolder. The only thing that you have to keep in mind is the Layout that will lay your ViewPlaceHolder. Suppose it is a RelativeLayout you can do something like this inside the ViewPlaceHolder constructor body :

```
public ViewPlaceHolder(View target) {
    super(target.getContext());
    this.target = target;
    int height = target.getHeight();
    int width  = target.getWidth();
    this.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height));
    this.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually the method I was using works, even if the view target hasn't been drawn yet.